# Spotfire IronPython script to open webpage

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I need to open a webpage using IronPython script as within the script I create a dynamic url. Did any of you try this ?

Comment: what would determine the url?

Comment: the url construction is not really a heart of this question - it just depends on the values in a set of columns in a table

Comment: I would try the same.